# IP range ban : At what level of subnet is there a risk of blocking legitimate traffic?

Tags: iptables, ip-banning

I want to automatically block IP that scanning my server (detected with portsentry) where several website are.

I don't know which level to choose to ban ip ranges. / 24, / 16 other? From what level is there a risk of false positives (legitimate traffic blocked)?

Example : this IP try an attack : 100.100.100.100, if I block 100.100.100.0/24 or 100.100.0.0/16 is it risky? What is the most appropriate level?

Comment: first you need to define what legitimate traffic is.
Is it a port or an IP range that you need to block? Is the IP known to be a "malicious" one? A simple VPN will allow any attacker to just change their IP

Comment: @Mixone I want to automatically block IP that scanning my server (detected with portsentry) where several website are. you think subnet using is not a good idea because legitimate traffic can be blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even blocking a single IP address can block lots of legitimate traffic. There have been times when an entire country shared a single IP address. As late as 2009, blocking 82.148.97.69 would have blocked thousands of people (though not all of Qatar as is sometimes reported).

Comment: You think using a tool like portsentry or fail2ban that blocks unique ip poses a great risk of blocking legitimate traffic?

Comment: My main visitors are in France, blocking Qatar doesn't matter to me.

Comment: @user2267379 The question doesn't really ask about a "great risk" but about a "a risk". I would say it depends what you're blocking. If it's the SSH port on a server, there is almost no risk. If it's the login scheme for a public-facing service, IP bans are unwise unless there are really no other options.

Comment: Theye days - carrier grade NAT and the fact that a lot of endpoints shall not be reached (mobile devices) and the iSP's love putting those behind NAT - means yes, even a single IP is more and more likely to block also legitimate users. Remember, we are OUT of ip addresses, so providers resort to NAT to save addresses, too.

Comment: ok I trust you. I thought at the beginning that the hackers did not use the same VPN as the public.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to stop the offender you will usually do fine to ban  the immediate IP block. I wouldn't go much further than that.

For example imagine I am being attacked by Vodaphone Australia

- I know the IP address is 202.142.xxx.yyy
- I go to this helpful site https://mxtoolbox.com/asn.aspx and type in the IP
- It tells me that I need to block 202.142.136.0/21 (2046 hosts)

Ultimately, it is up to you to decide how severe the attack is vs the amount of potential legitimate traffic you might lose. We can't help with that.

**Edit** If you want to do it programatically whois has you covered:

```
# Stackoverflow
whois 199.115.115.119 | grep -o "inetnum:.*"

# inetnum:      199.0.0.0 - 199.255.255.255
```